# undefined reference when trying to compile

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I've been googling nonstop, and can't see where i'm going wrong. the problem boils down to, I have a .cc file called queens.cc. the header files are in the directory /headers. there are also some library files, in /libraries.

now using this code:

```
g++ -o queens -L/libraries -I/headers queens.cc
```

no matter i try, it always just gives several of these type of errors:
queens.cc:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `allocateState(unsigned char)`

I know this is because it's trying to call a function from the library in /libraries. I've used -L so it will look for and use my libraries, but that doesn't seem to work... any help would be greatly appreciated. i also know it's a linker error.

Comment: you HAVE to specify what libraries you will use to the linker with the '-lLibname' command